# "filename too long" bash mv command old files

Tags: bash, shell, unix, mv

```
#! /bin/sh -
cd /PHOTAN || exit
fn=$(ls -t | tail -n -30)
mv -f -- "${fn}" /old
```

all I want todo is keep most recent 30 files... but cant get past the mv 
"File name too long" problem

please help'

Answer (score 3):

The notation `"${fn}"` adds all the file names into a single argument string, separated by spaces.  Just for once, assuming you don't have to worry about file names with spaces in them, you need:

```
mv -f -- ${fn} /old
```

If you have file names with spaces in them, then you've got problems starting with parsing the output of the `ls` command.

> But what if you do have to worry about spaces in your filenames?

Then, as I stated, you have major problems, starting with the issues of parsing the output of `ls`.

```
$ echo > 'a  b'
$ echo > '  c  d  '
$
```

Two nice file names with spaces in them.  They cause merry hell.  I'm about to assume you're on Linux or something similar enough.  You need to use `bash` arrays, the `stat` command, `printf`, `sort -z`, `sed -z`.  Or you should simply outlaw filenames with spaces; it is probably easier.

```
names=( * )
```

The array `names` contains each file name as a separate array element, leading and trailing and embedded blanks all handled correctly.

```
names=( * )
for file in "${names[@]}"
do printf "%s\0" "$(stat -c '%Y' "$file") $file"
done |
sort -nzr |
sed  -nze '1,30s/^[0-9][0-9]* //p' |
tr '\0' '\n'
```

The `for` loop evaluates the modification time of each file separately, and combines the modification time, a space, and the file name into a single string followed by a null byte to mark the end of the string.  The `sort` command sorts the 'lines' numerically, assuming the lines are terminated by null bytes because of the `-z` option, and places the most recent file names first.  The `sed` command prints the first 30 'lines' (file names) only; the `tr` command replaces null bytes with newlines (but in doing so, loses the identity of file name boundaries).

The code works even with file names containing newlines, but only on systems where `sed` and `sort` support the (non-standard) `-z` option to process null-terminated input 'lines' — that means systems using GNU `sed` and `sort` (even BSD `sed` as found on Mac OS X does not, though the Mac OS X `sort` is GNU `sort` and does support `-z`).

Ugh!  The shell was designed for spaces to appear between and not within file names.

---

As noted by [BroSlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076724/broslow) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696474/filename-too-long-bash-mv-command-old-files#comment40167953_25696493), if you assume 'no newlines in filenames', then the code can be simpler and more nearly portable — but it is still tricky:

```
ls -t |
tail -30 |
{
list=()
while IFS='' read -r file
do list+=( "$file" )
done
mv -f -- "${list[@]}" /old
}
```

The `IFS=''` is needed so that leading and trailing spaces in filenames are preserved (and tabs, too).

I note in passing that the Korn shell would not require the braces but Bash does.

Comment: But what if you do have to worry about spaces in your filenames?

Comment: Then you've got major problems!  Let me meditate on it; it is extremely unpleasant, whatever.  Are you on Linux or some other Unix-like platform?

Comment: Could just assume no files with newlines and parse `ls` output. But +1 for completeness.